# How do i convert Boolean to String in Solidity?

Tags: string, convert

The problem is pretty simple: I want to concatenate boolean values to string values. I order to do this, i assume they have to first be converted into strings and then concatenated.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Paul's solution does what you want. On a side note, there is no concatenation operator in solidity, and you really should avoid dealing with strings in solidity as much as you can. Why are you trying to do that specific thing if i may ask?

Comment: I have a property (boolean). all metadata within the contract is generated onchain and the tokenuri function creates a something like a json file in the browser. 

within this tokenuri function i have to set up the json format. everything i put into it has to be supplied as a string

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertBoolToString(bool input) external pure returns (string memory) {
    if (input) {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

Comment: i opted out for a solution that can be compared to this one: A mapping with "true" and "false" and another mapping that saves 0 or 1 for each token ID. this later is combined with the true/false mapping in order to generate those strings. Im not sure which solution uses less gas

Answer (score 0):

Another option for serializing multiple flags is to use the `abi.encodePacked` method, though you will get the `bytes` type, but it is better to deal with than strings.

```typescript
function test() view external returns (bytes memory) {
    return abi.encodePacked(true, true, false));
}
// 0x010100
```

Comment: i do not understand this solition, as your function takes no input parameters and therefore i dont see how it can convert a boolean to a string